# difference between basic_iostream and iostream?

Tags: c++, templates, io, stream

I have done my research before posting this question,and made sure there was not similar questions asked.

I am reading this article http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/cp10_io.html on streams in C++,and in the diagram in the link I noticed in blue there is basic_iostream and underneath it in green is iostream,the same goes for basic_ifstream and ifstream and so on,

from what I read is that basic_iostream is a template class and iostream is an instantiation of basic_iostream,but what is meant by this?

iostream is not an object like cout,cin and cerr so how is it an instantiation?

Comment: *"from what I read is that basic_iostream is a template class and iostream is an instantiation of basic_iostream,but what is meant by this?"* What do you mean by that? That's exactly describing the situation, what exactly is unclear to you?

Comment: *"iostream is not an object like cout,cin and cerr so how is it an instantiation?"* And how did you get the idea that template instantiations must be objects? You might be missing some basics here; it would probably help to re-read the relevant sections in your C++ text book.

Comment: how did this question possibly get a -1? it is a valid question.

Comment: Is this helpful to you? *"In order to support various character sets (char and wchar_t in C++98/03; and char16_t, char32_t introduced in C++11), the stream classes are written as template classes, which could be instantiated with an actual character type."*

Comment: "And how did you get the idea that template instantiations must be objects?"
template_class<int> obj; is a template class instantiation  and obj is the object created , how can you create a template instantiation without creating an object? could you link me to a post

Comment: Read: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_iostream  Specifically the lines below _"Two specializations for common character types are defined:"_

Comment: @strikeforcefan2013 -- don't let the snarky comments bother you. People here tend to forget what it was like when they were just starting out.

Comment: oh ok I think I'm getting the point now,but even with a define or typedef you cannot create a template instantiation (could be called a class instantiation,sorry if I'm wrong) with an object being created right ? as my example in the comments above

Comment: much appreciated Pete,I take it in good stride it's part of been the new guy

Comment: There 's a lot of terminology to wrap your head around. Most of the time a good book can straighten it out, but some times you need couple books, a web presentation or two and a question on Stack Overflow to get it right.

Comment: `typedef some_template_class<some_template_parameters> instantiation;`?

Comment: sorry let me rephrase that I need to slow down and be clearer,oh ok I think I'm understanding now,but even with a define or typedef you cannot create a template instantiation (could be called a class instantiation,sorry if I'm wrong) without an object being created right ? for example vector<int> vec; a template instantiation or class instantiation will take place but also an object name vec will also be created.

Comment: I think that's where the explanation is trying to go. An instance is typically defined in OOP as an object at runtime. But more generally an instance is something made out of a blueprint. A class is made out of a template, so if you don't mind confusion with the usual definition, you could say that a class is an instance of a template. Also keep an eye out for Specialization, Partial Specialization and probably even Double Secret Specialization.

Comment: that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In namespace std there's a typedef:

```
typedef basic_iostream<char, char_traits<char>> iostream;
```

That defines `iostream` as a synonym for `basic_iostream<char, char_traits<char>>`. When you write something like

```
std::iostream my_stream;
```

you are, in effect, writing

```
std::basic_iostream<char, std::char_traits<char>> my_stream.
```